# How to make edit function that replaces existing text for To-Do App?

Tags: javascript

I created an `editItem function` which creates the HTML element when the user clicks on the edit button, I am not sure how to go about when the user inputs, when the update replaces the existing task.

I am aware that the `replace` can be used to replace the `new-task-created` class in the `renderList`

Just a note I created a new object `updateEl` which contains the class of the modal and I also created `updateTask function` which returns the new values been inserted.

My thinking pattern is this: If I need to create new values for the user input, time, and date, that new information can just replace the old information when they click save (`UpdateTask function`)

HTML

```html
<div class="form">
   <input class ="user-input" type="text">
   <input class="date" type="date">
   <input class="time" type="time">
   <button onclick="addTask()" class="add" id="add">+</button>
</div>

  <div class="list"></div>
<div class="modal"></div>
```

JS

```
//local storage key
const STORAGE_KEY = "tasks-storage-key";

// variables object
const el = {
  form: document.querySelector(".form"),
  input: document.querySelector(".user-input"),
  list: document.querySelector(".list"),
  date: document.querySelector(".date"),
  time: document.querySelector(".time"),
};

const updateEl = {
  formUpdate: document.querySelector(".form-update"),
  inputUpdate: document.querySelector(".user-input"),
  modal: document.querySelector(".modal"),
  dateUpdate: document.querySelector(".date-update"),
  timeUpdate: document.querySelector(".time-update"),
};

//Create ID

const createId = () =>
  `${Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000)}${new Date().getTime()}`;

//variable of empty array that gets new task
let taskList = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem(STORAGE_KEY) ?? "[]");

renderList();

function makeNewTask() {
  const data = {
    id: createId(),
    taskNew: el.input.value,
    taskDate: el.date.value,
    taskTime: el.time.value,
  };

  return data;
}

function updateTask() {
  const dataUpdate = {
    id: createId(),
    inputUpdate: updateEl.inputUpdate.value,
    dateUpdate: updateEl.dateUpdate.value,
    timeUpdate: updateEl.timeUpdate.value,
  };

  return dataUpdate;
}


function renderList() {
  // This resets the list innerHTML to the new list
  el.list.innerHTML = taskList.map(function (data) {
    return `<div class="task">
            <div class="task-content">
                <div class="task" data-id="${data.id}">
                <div class="new-task-created">${data.taskNew}</div>
                <label class="due-date">${data.taskDate}</label>
                <label class="due-time">${data.taskTime}</label>
            </div>
    
            <div class="action-buttons">
                <button onclick="editItem(event)" class="edit" data-id="${data.id}">Edit</button>
                <button onclick="deleteItem(event)" class="delete" data-id="${data.id}">Delete</button>
                <button onclick="completeItem(event)" class="complete" data-id="${data.id}">Complete</button>
            </div>
        </div>`;
  });

  
}

//event listner that listens for add button.
function addTask() {
  taskList.push(makeNewTask());
  // store the list on localstorage because data changed
  storeList();
  // render list again because you've added a new entry
  renderList();
  
}

//function that removes task from array with delete button.
function deleteItem(event) {
  taskList.splice(taskList.indexOf(event.target.dataset.id), 1);
  // store the list on localstorage because data changed
  storeList();
  // render list again because entry was removed
  renderList();
}

//function that stores task list.
function storeList() {
  window.localStorage.setItem(STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(taskList));
}

//function that that edits tasks with date and time.
function editItem() {

  let updateInput = document.createElement("div")
  updateInput.innerHTML = `<div class="form-update">
        <input class ="input-update" type="text">
        <input class="date-update" type="date">
        <input class="time-update" type="time">
        <button onclick="UpdateTask()" class="update" id="update">Save</button>
        <button onclick="close()" class="close" id="close">Save</button>
    </div>`;

    updateEl.modal.appendChild(updateInput);
}


function UpdateTask(){

}


//function that that completes task.
function completeItem(event) {
  const element = event.target.closest(".task-content");
  let taskItem = element.querySelector(".new-task-created");
  let dateItem = element.querySelector(".due-date");
  let timeItem = element.querySelector(".due-time");
  // style..
  taskItem.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
  dateItem.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
  timeItem.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
}
```

Comment: *"...new information can just replace the old information when they click save"* Yes, exactly , you'll notice your code will have less bloat.

Comment: That is the outcome I want, but I am not sure how to achieve that in the ```function UpdateTask(){

}``` as that function needs to do the replacing from the old to the new

Answer (score 0):

I got it to update doing it this way.

```
function editItem(event) {

const editEl = event.target.closest(".task");
let taskUpdate = editEl.querySelector(".new-task-created");
let dateUpdate = editEl.querySelector(".due-date");
let timeUpdate = editEl.querySelector(".due-time");
let editbtn = editEl.querySelector(".edit");

if (editbtn.innerHTML.toLowerCase() == "edit"){
  taskUpdate.removeAttribute("readonly");
  dateUpdate.removeAttribute("readonly");
  timeUpdate.removeAttribute("readonly");
  taskUpdate.focus();

  editbtn.innerHTML = "Save";

}
else{
  taskUpdate.setAttribute("readonly", "readonly");
  dateUpdate.setAttribute("readonly", "readonly");
  timeUpdate.setAttribute("readonly", "readonly");
  editbtn.innerHTML = "Edit";
}
```